# Getting segmentation fault when running code twice

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I'm programming for an assignment in C, and we have to translate logical formulas.

For one part, we need to convert a formula in the following way:
φ <-> ψ → (φ & ψ) | (~φ & ~ψ)

The data algorithm is a binary tree.

The code that translates the contents of the tree is the following function:

```c
int translate2(FormTree *tree) {
    //for1 <-> for2 = (for1 & for2) | (~for1 & ~for2)
    if((*tree)->tt == Symbol && (*tree)->t.symbol == 1) {
        Token neg, con, dis;
        neg.symbol = '~';
        con.symbol = '&';
        dis.symbol = '|';

        FormTree pt1 = newFormTreeNode(Symbol, con, (*tree)->left, (*tree)->right);

        FormTree negl = newFormTreeNode(Symbol, neg, (*tree)->left, NULL);
        FormTree negr = newFormTreeNode(Symbol, neg, (*tree)->right, NULL);

        FormTree pt2 = newFormTreeNode(Symbol, con, negl, negr);

        *tree = newFormTreeNode(Symbol, dis, pt1, pt2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The main function asks the user to insert a formula, a scanning module (which should be written correctly, as our lecturers gave it to us) puts it in a binary tree, and we have to translate it and print the result. Then the program starts again by asking the user for another formula.

When I run the program and enter, for example *a <-> b*, the program translates it correctly. However, when I enter it a second time, the program crashes with a segmentation fault. From some debugging I learned that this error occurs when creating the *pt2* FormTree.

The newFormTreeNode function:

```c
FormTree newFormTreeNode(TokenType tt, Token t, FormTree tL, FormTree tR) {
    FormTree new = malloc(sizeof(FormTreeNode));
    assert (new != NULL);
    new->tt = tt;
    new->t = t;
    new->left = tL;
    new->right = tR;
    return new;
}
```

formtree header file:

```c
typedef struct FormTreeNode *FormTree;

typedef struct FormTreeNode {
  TokenType tt;
  Token t;
  FormTree left;
  FormTree right;
} FormTreeNode;

FormTree newFormTreeNode(TokenType tt, Token t, FormTree tL, FormTree tR);
```

And last but not least, the main function:

```js
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 char *ar;
 List tl, tl1;
 tl1 = NULL;
 printf("enter a formula: ");
 ar = readInput();
 while (ar[0] != '!') {
  tl = tokenList(ar);
  printList(tl);
  tl1 = tl;
  FormTree t = NULL;
  if ( treeFormula(&tl1,&t)!=0 && tl1 == NULL ) {
   translate2(&t);
   
   printf("translated: ");
   printTree(t);
   printf("\n");

   freeTree(t);
  } else {
   printf("this is not a formula\n");
   if (t != NULL) {
    freeTree(t);
   }
  }
  free(ar);
  freeTokenList(tl);
  printf("\nenter a formula: ");
  ar = readInput();
 }
 free(ar);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are things missing from the code. Provide a [mre].

Comment: It would be helpful if you do not hide pointers in typedefs. E.g. `typedef struct FormTreeNode *FormTree;` It makes the code difficult to read if we do not see the pointer symbol in the code.

Comment: You have: `FormTree t = NULL;` then `treeFormula(&tl1,&t)` might change `t` or not, then   `translate2(&t);` binding `tree` to `&t` which in turn has `(*tree)->tt` before check for null pointer.